# Media Queries working on Desktop browser but not mobile device

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently working on making my portfolio site responsive. My media queries seem to be working on desktop but as soon as i look at it on mobile (iPhone 4) things get out of whack.

Here's a picture of how it appears on my iPhone 4

[image: iPhone 4 Web View]

For some reason the `background` seems cut off even though the media query `width` should cover the device, and also my mobile `nav` hasn't loaded in. I've been looking into this for a few hours and still cant seem to find the problem.

Here's the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

(I tried setting the initial scale on this as well and it only made things worse)

Here's how I'm calling the query with CSS

**CSS**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:400px) and (max-width:499px) { 

}
```

I have other breakpoints as well, but this is the smallest one

[Here](http://www.kylebinger.com) is the live site in action so you can see the difference between the desktop and mobile versions

Answer (score 1):

because you are setting a `min-width:400px` on your **last** `media-query`, which mean than any device under `400px` will be having the regular CSS you set,

Solution:remove `min-width:400px` or create another `media query`.

I would advise you, to not use `min-width` and `max-width` in the same `media query`, it will make you to write more code.

So, either

- use the mobile approach, which is using **only** `min-width`

or

- use the non-mobile approach, which is using **only** `max-width`

with those option your queries will be have less code than your first option you are using now.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

instead of the viewport you've added. if this doesn't work, one of your element must be taking more space than the screen size itself (see if you can scroll left or right).

Edited 10 mins later
I just Checked, this is the Issue, 
try adding

```
#car{
width: 100%;
}
```

as well and you'll see the difference, you need to adjust the font sizes and more. I'm guessing you've just begun with web development?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I am wondering though how this is the problem, because in my media query i set the width of the car to fit in the window, if the window is 400px the car should be 380px and centered, and shouldnt be taking up more room than the view port

Comment: Also when i put in initial-scale=1 to the meta tag, everything seems greatly enlarged on my phone, and my media queries still dont load in, the main way to tell this is my mobile hamburger menu doesnt load in in place of the regular nav

Comment: initial-scale=1 is basically like the zooming property. I believe your trying to get is <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75">

Comment: don't forget to check the after affects on other screens

Comment: I just checked.. It'll fix it, and nice quote about the design up-front. (Y)